# How to get top 5 maximum values keys in pyspark red using filter

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

```
Rdd=sc.parallelize([('a',1),('b',5),('c',3),('d',7),('e',10),('f',5),('g',9)])
```

I have this kind of rdd in pyspark and I want top 5 keys with max value.

Answer (score 0):

`rdd.sort('column_name', ascending=False).take(5)`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with RDDs, you can sort your data and take the first 5 elements.

```
>>> Rdd.sortBy(lambda x : - x[1]).take(5)
[('e', 10), ('g', 9), ('d', 7), ('f', 5), ('b', 5)]
```

Yet, this may not be very efficient, especially on large RDDs. You could use a simple reduce.

```
Rdd.map(lambda x: [x])\
   .reduce(lambda a,b: sorted(a + b, key = lambda x : - x[1])[:5] )
```

This is still not optimal because this will yield quite a lot of object creations, but already much better than a sort.